# Wall post doesn't appear on facebook posted by my application: Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

I am using [Facebook API](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) in my application to post messages to wall. Every thing work fine, but when I post message more than one time in a sort time interval, wall post doesn't appear on wall. I am sure there no any exception occurres while posting.

I use 'offline-access' permission with my application.

Code :

```
public static class UpdateWalls extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
        private Context context;
        private String post;

        public UpdateWalls(Context context, String post) {
            this.context = context;
            this.post = post; 
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

            FacebookConnector facebookConnector = new FacebookConnector(Constants.FACEBOOK_APPID, context, Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSION);
            try {
                facebookConnector.postMessageOnWall(this.post);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }           
            return true;
        }   
    }
```

and *FacebookConnector.postMessageOnWall() is*

```
public void postMessageOnWall(String msg) {
        if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", msg);
            try {
                String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
                Log.i("Facebook wall post", "While posting to wall response = " + response);

                //System.out.println(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //login();
        }
    }
```

Is this a known issue or something else? Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: This code is irrelevant to what you're asking. The code that you should post is of *FacebookConnector*, and what's *post*? Just the message?

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer What do you mean of irrelevant? Are you asking about code of FacebookConnector? And yes I am posting message with string only.

Comment: Yeah, the code in the *FacebookConnector* class is what's doing to actual posting, and since it's not a class from the SDK then we have no way of knowing what's going on there..  You should post that code.

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer I updated the code.

Comment: Ok, so you're sure that no exception is thrown? What about the response? For posts that are not posted, what do you get back from the request?

Comment: getting While posting to wall response = {"id":"100003220708339_2174330385450536"} in response

Comment: If you're getting an id back then it means that the post was successfully added. If it does not, then try to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook API, in most cases, won't throw exceptions even if the request fails. Error status is returned by the response to the call. In this line here:

```
Log.i("Facebook wall post", "While posting to wall response = " + response);
```

You're writing a log with the response. What is that response? What is it when the wall post succeeds compared to when it fails?

It seems facebook reject requests when they come in too fast, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492552/facebook-api-limits) for a short but possibly out-of-date discussion on API limits. If you're getting a response that suggests you're making too many requests, you could add a delay and try again.