# Rate limit on Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting

I am working on a project that want to use facebook api's. I want to know whether there is a rate limit on the facebook api's per account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492552/facebook-api-limits)

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a rate limit for Facebook API which is also mentioned in their [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) as

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please [contact us](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=206103619499608) as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the Platform Policies mentioned in the pervious answer, the Facebook graph API is subject to multiple level of rate limiting / throttling -- user (access token) level, app level (app id), API level, and IP address.

This doc. has most of what you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/, other than the IP level throttling.

This post cover the IP level throttling: [Facebook Graph API limit - per token and per IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983033/facebook-graph-api-limit-per-token-and-per-ip)